# Pandas groupby multiple columns, count, and resample

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

Having the following dataframe:

```
                     UserID TweetLanguage
2014-08-25 21:00:00  001        english
2014-08-27 21:04:00  001        arabic
2014-08-29 22:07:00  001        espanish
2014-08-25 22:09:00  002        english
2014-08-26 22:09:00  002        espanish
2014-08-25 22:09:00  003        english
```

I need to plot the weekly number of users who have posted in more than one language.

For example, in the above dataframe, user 001 and 002 have tweeted in more than one languages. So in the plot, the corresponding value for this week should be 2. Same story for other weeks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
df.groupby([pd.Grouper(freq='W'), 'User ID'])['TweetLanguage'].nunique().unstack().plot()
```

Comment: Nice, I was wondering what column was his datetime, looks like it's index so no key needed.

Comment: Many thanks. But this gives the frequency for each language. Not the number of language for each user.

Answer (score 2):

```
df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='datetime', freq='W')).apply(lambda df:\
df.groupby('UserID').apply(lambda df: len(df.TweetLanguage.value_counts())))
```

This is a one liner that will seperate the week and get number of language in a week

```
df.groupby('UserID').apply(lambda df: len(df.TweetLanguage.value_counts()))
```

This will return a series with index: value of user ID : number of language used for each week..

Comment: However, this does not give weekly stats as indicated in the question. I would give each day a corresponding week number and use an extended groupby statement.

Comment: Yes you're correct, I think the better way to do it is to seperate the weeks first. Potentially doable in one line but probably not very pythonic

Comment: Thanks. But the first code doesn't work. It give this error: 'TimeGrouper' object has no attribute 'apply'

Comment: I missed a `)` lol, also, if the datetime field is the index, you don't need the `key` argument in the first `groupby`

Answer (score 2):

Use 2 `groupbys`. The first finds the users who post in more than one language every week, the second counts how many there are per week.

```
(df.groupby([df.index.year.rename('year'), df.index.week.rename('week'), 'UserID']).TweetLanguage.nunique() > 1).groupby(level=[0,1]).sum()

#year  week
#2014  35      2.0
#Name: TweetLanguage, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Many thanks. But this only works for one year (due to df.index.week). For the next years, it adds the count to the previous year.

Comment: @msmazh see the update. You should be able to use `pd.to_datetime` to create a `datetime` out of the year and week fairly easily if you need to plot these as dates over multiple years.